# Adding date to the form

Tags: python, django

I have model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    thread = model.ForeignKey(Thread)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Anonymous')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

And I have form:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'text']
```

I don't use date field in the form. How can I add current date, when I send the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the declaration of the date field to:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This will make the date field change to now on every insert or update. If you want it only on the insert you can change it to `auto_now_add=True`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) for more details.

Comment: @K1m do you have records in the existing database that have `Post.date == None` ? Test it: `SELECT * IN posts WHERE date IS NULL`

Comment: @AdamSmith No. Actually, my Post have foreign key and I think, it remains empty.